# What is the proper method of doing data-transfer between Azure Databases?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I'm completely new to Azure and I am charged with an effort to regularly migrate/replicate (various) data between Azure Databases (and eventually across regions).  In my mind, I was thinking we would simply write & install SSIS Packages on each consumer to do gather-up data from publishers.  In a meeting, however, it was stated by folks that you shouldn't use SSIS for this, and that, using the Service Bus or Web Roles or Workers were the way to accomplish this.

But...after double-checking & reading-up on the Service Bus and Web Roles & Workers...I don't see them as useful for my need.  Am I wrong?

**Q:** What is the proper method of doing data-transfer between Azure Databases?
**Q:** How might the strategies differ between IAAS versus SAAS etc.?

**UPDATE**
I am looking for ways to migrate portions of schema, as well as, update existing schema (rather than replication a database as-a-whole).  For instance, normally, if I had geographical data in a "geo" schema and wanted to make it available to others, I would create an SSIS package that others could install & schedule.  However, I am being told SSIS is not the way to do this between Azure Database instance...hence, the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you go for the newly announced Azure SQL Database Premium you would automatically get up to 4 geo-replicated readable replicas (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741340.aspx).

If you are looking to replicate on-premise data you can consider the Azure-backup features that were introduced with SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU2 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

if you dont require full database replication/synchronization, but only require selecting specific table/columns/data to transfer, here's some options:

1. [Azure SQL Data Sync Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh456372.aspx) - this service is available on Azure that allows you to sync Azure SQL Databases and even on-premise/cloud-hosted VMs with SQL installations (LocalDb,Express,Server). Unfortunately, it's just a Preview release (i think it now holds the distinction of longest running Preview for an Azure service).
2. As mentioned by Jk_xp, you can use Sync Framework for this. there's a sample here for an Azure hosted sync service: [Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1568.walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx). This sample will work with on-premise to Azure or Azure to Azure scenarios.
3. If you're synching between Azure SQL Databases and you don't mind setting up a SQL VM on Azure, there's SSIS on an Azure SQL VM as an option.

there's some nice readings here as well:

[Cloud Design Patterns - Data Replication and Synchronization Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589787.aspx)

[Appendix A - Replicating, Distributing, and Synchronizing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868047.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the new Azure Data Factory service to move selected data between Azure SQL databases.  Transfers can be scheduled and contain data transformation logic analogous to SSIS, but provided as a service in Azure.  See [Data Factory Copy Operations](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-copy-activity/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: The proper method to sync data between SQL Servers (Azure or on-premise) is to use Microsoft Sync Framework. You can write your own flexible sync process. Here is a few links to start with:

- [Link 1](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/tr/tr/sync-framework.aspx)
- [Link 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx)
- [Link 3](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1591.sync-framework-sql-server-to-windows-azure-sql-database-synchronization.aspx)

Q2: The difference in strategy would be in the way where you will host/run your sync process - WorkerRole (PAAS), Virtual Machine (IAAS) or somewhere on-premise (if applicable). I would suggest worker role as the most convenient way to maintain and the same price as VM.

**UPD:**
Per your comment: You can crate an Azure project with a WorkerRole. Then you can write your own sync logic (example is [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1591.sync-framework-sql-server-to-windows-azure-sql-database-synchronization.aspx)). Your worker role can listen a storage queue for an incoming messages (see an example [here, section "Handle the message"](http://www.remondo.net/messaging-between-roles-using-azure-queue-storage-service/)). Then whenever somebody posts a message into the queue - the sync process gets executed.

If your sync process needs to be scheduled, you can post a message with Azure Scheduler (see [Post a message to an Azure Storage Queue](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/))

If your process is on demand - just write your piece of code to send a message into the queue (as in the roles communication example above). Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please expand on your comment of using a Worker Role to migrate data?  Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft Sync Framework can sync both data and schema. It is the new and (IMHO) best way to sync SQL databases in cloud/hybrid environments.

Comment: Correct. SSIS is not suitable for Azure because SQL Azure does not support SSIS packages and the only way to use SSIS in Azure is to get Virtual Machine with full SQL Server (very expensive). Unless you already have VM with SQL Server in use, a Worker Role and Sync Framework will be much more cost-effective, more flexible, salable and maintainable.

Comment: just an update: i just found out that you actually don't need to have full SQL Server installed to run SSIS on VM, which brings the cost to the same level as a Worker Role. But still Sync Framework is more convenient way.

Comment: Sync Framework does not sync schemas, only data. Any changes you make to your schema after you provision will not be picked up and synched. Neither is Sync Fx new, it hasn't actually been updated for years.

Comment: @JuneT, thanks, it seems that i was wrong. What would you recommend to sync schemas?

Comment: @JuneT, Could you possibly submit an answer.  Or maybe, help us update this one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To throw other options into the mix, you can also use the following techniques:

- **SQL Server BCP**: This has lots of flexibility but will persist your data in intermediate files. If you run BCP from a VM in Azure in the region where you have your databases, then you avoid copying the data to on-premise.
- **Distributed query**: You can run a regular SQL Server IaaS instance in Azure VMs and register your source and target servers as linked servers. You can then run a SELECT INTO statement to copy the data and shape it for your target database/table with the query that you run.

To avoid paying for the VM when it is idle, think about running it only for the times when you do the data movement and shutting it down after that. You don't have to delete the VM.